# Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fpog\resources\views\pages\index.blade.php)

Tags: laravel-routing

The code on my PostsController is this

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(8);
    return view('pages.index')->with('posts',$posts);
}
```

The code on my index page is this:

```
            @if(count($posts) > 0)
            @foreach($posts as $post)
              <div class="well">
              <h5><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h5>
                <small>Posted on {{$post->created_at}} </small>
              </div><hr>
            @endforeach
              <div class="text-center">
                {{$posts->links()}}
              </div>
          @else
              <p>No Post is on this page</p>
          @endif
```

Please help a stuck brother